# Custom matchers in Rspec. What is the match do block?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am reading this code from RSpec:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end

RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
end
```

What is the `match do` block? It's a block inside a proc? The syntax is a bit odd... is the `define` method taking two arguments; the first is a symbol and the second is a `Proc`?

Under the hood... how does `actual` refer to the integer 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expect(object).to eq(value)
         |         |   |
         |         |  expected (matcher argument)
         |         |
       actual      |
                matcher
```

> What's happening in this code?

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
```

When `RSpec::Matcher.define` is called, it is passed the ***name of a matcher*** ( which in this case is `be_a_multiple_of` )  and a ***block***

The argument passed to that block is the **expected** value. This is the value passed as the ***matcher argument*** when running a spec, which would be **3** in this case `be_a_multiple_of(3)`

```
match do |actual|
```

Inisde that **block**, the ***match*** method is called which is also passed a block.  That block takes one argument, **actual**, which is the value passed to `expect` when the matcher is invoked. In this case that would be **9**, `expect(9).to be_multipe_of(3)`

The block just does some calculation using `actual` and `expected` to return ***true*** or ***false***.

> How does actual refer to 9?

```
RSpec.describe 9 do
```

In this case the value **9** is exposed as the *subject* for the ***example group*** because it is passed as the argument to the outermost example group as stated [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-8/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject#subject-exposed-in-top-level-group) In other words it's the same as writing `subject { 9 }`

If you check the [RSpec doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax) `is_expected` is basically the same as writing `expect(subject)`.

```
{ is_expected.to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
```

is the same as

```
{ expect(subject).to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
```

And as stated earlier the object passed to **expect** method is what is used as the **actual** argument for the block passed to the *match* method. That's how `actual` refers to `9`